# Prove: Existence of holomorphic primitive if and only if all residues are zero.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $D$ be a star domain and $a_1, \dots, a_n \in D$. I want to show that a holomorphic function $f: D\setminus\{a_1, \dots, a_n\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ has a primitive if and only if $\text{res}_{z=a_i} f = 0$ for all $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.

I already got the first implication:

$"\implies"$: We have for sufficiently small $r > 0:$
$$\text{res}_{z=a_i}f=\int_{|z-a_i|=r}f(z)\,\text{d}z$$
And $f$ has a primitive this integral vanishes.

Sadly I'm stuck proving the second implication and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose an arbitrary fixed $z_0 \in D$ and define $$F(z) = \int_{z_0}^z f(w) \, dw$$ for $z \in D$, where the integration is done along an arbitrary path $\gamma$ connecting $z_0$ with $z$ in $D$. Use the residue theorem to show that the the definition is independent of the choice of $\gamma$, so that $F$ is well-defined.

Finally show that $F' = f$: Let $z_1 \in D$ and $\epsilon > 0$. There is a $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta(z_1) \subset D$ and $|f(w) - f(z_1)| < \epsilon$ for all $w \in B_\delta(z_1)$. Then for all $z_2 \in  B_\delta(z_1)$ with $z_2 \ne z_1$
$$
 \frac{F(z_2) - F(z_1)}{z_2 - z_1} = \frac{1}{z_2 - z_1}\int_{[z_1, z_2]} f(w) \, dw =  \int_0^1 f(z_1 + (z_2 - z_1) t) \, dt
$$
and therefore
$$
\left| \frac{F(z_2) - F(z_1)}{z_2 - z_1}  - f(z_1) \right| \le \int_0^1 \bigl|f(\underbrace{z_1 + (z_2 - z_1) t}_{\in B_\delta(z_1)}) -f(z_1)\bigr|\, dt \le \varepsilon \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you! I'll try. Is my first implication correct though?

Comment: @user7802048: Yes, it is.

Comment: I proved the path independence, but how do I approach $F’=f$?

Comment: @user7802048: See update.

Comment: I would criticize "Use the residue theorem" the residue is defined as $2i\pi Res(f,a)=\int_{|z-a|=\epsilon} f(z)dz$ so (once we know the Cauchy integral theorem) it is by definition that $\int_{z_0}^zf(w)dw$ doesn't depend on the path $z_0 \to z$ iff all the residue vanish @user7802048

Comment: @reuns: I am referring to [this version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) of the residue theorem, which states that the integral along a closed path is the sum of residues at the $a_k$, multiplied with  the corresponding winding numbers. If all residues are zero then the integral along every closed path is zero, so that $\int_{z_0}^z$ does not depend on the chosen path.

Comment: I'm used to the same residue theorem as @MartinR. Thank you. I'm not quite sure, why the last integral converges to $f$ though when $f$ is continuous? Does this involve the Leibnitz rule?

Comment: @user7802048: It's much more simple. $t$ is restricted to the interval $[0, 1]$, so that $z_1 + (z_2- z_1)t$ is close to $f(z_1)$ when $z_2$ is close to $z_1$. You only need the continuity of $f$ at $z_1$.

Comment: @MartinR I see the limes for every fixed $t$, but don't know what rule tells me about how to get the limes inside the integral.

Comment: @user7802048: See update.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you, I feel stupid for the continuity now.. We can remove $t$ by writing the inner part of the integral as $f(z_0) \pm  epsilon$ and this will just yield $f(z_0) \pm \epsilon$.