# Residues and existence of complex antiderivative

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, curves, residue-calculus

I know that there already is a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3374509/prove-existence-of-holomorphic-primitive-if-and-only-if-all-residues-are-zero) out there but I am not really satisfied with that answer. I think it is too complicated. Assume that $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open and simply connected, $P \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ has finite cardinality and $f: G \setminus P \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. Then

$f$ has an antiderivative on its domain $\iff $ $\mathrm{Res}_p(f) = 0 ~\forall p \in P$.

Can I argue the following way? The crucial part is the second implication.

"$ \implies$": Since $f$ has an antiderivative, all integrals over closed rectifiable curves vanish. If I let $p \in P$ be arbitrary and $\varepsilon > 0$ so small that $\partial B_\varepsilon(p) \subseteq G \setminus P$, then according to the residue theorem:
$$
0 = \int_{\partial B_\varepsilon(p)} f(z)~\mathrm{d}z = 2 \pi i\mathrm{Res}_p(f)
$$

"$\impliedby$": For any closed rectifiable curve $\gamma$ we have:
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)~\mathrm{d}z = \sum_{p \in P} I_p(\gamma) \mathrm{Res}_p(f) = 0
$$
Therefore the existence of a primitive.

Comment: Your $\impliedby$ part is essentially what I tried to express with “Use the residue theorem to show that the definition is independent of the choice of $\gamma$,” i.e. that $F(z) = \int_{z_0}^z f(w) \, dw$ is well-defined. It still remains to show that $F'(x) = f(x)$, and that is what the remaining part in my answer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the given conditions on $G$, $P$, and $f$, the following three statements are equivalent:

- (a) $f$ has an antiderivative in $G$.
- (b) $\operatorname{Res}_p(f) = 0 $ for all $ p \in P$.
- (c) $\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = 0$ for all closed rectifiable curves $\gamma$ in $G$.

What you have demonstrated is that $(a) \implies (b)$ and that $(b) \implies (c)$.

It remains to show that $(c) \implies (a)$, and that can be done by showing that $F(z) = \int_{z_0}^z f(w) \, dw$ (which is well-defined under the condition (c)) satisfies $F' = f$.

Comment: $(c)\Rightarrow(a)$ is probably known to OP as a prerequisite. It's a pretty standard thing to show early on in a complex analysis course.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos: That may be, but I do not know. OP considered https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3374520/42969 as “not satisfying” and “too complicated” therefore I tried to clarify the various steps in the argumentation. – If my answer turns out to be not useful to the question author then I will delete it.

Comment: @MartinR It is very useful, thanks, it was my mistake. I skipped (c) $\implies$ (a) because I assumed it to be obvious. I failed to recognize this step in your aforementioned answer, which is a very nice one.